# FacetWP filter from custom field checkbox

Tags: wordpress, facetwp

I got a product custom field named organic with the values yes/no. I want to show a checkbox in our filter that says "Organic". And when checked search for yes values in db. The deafult setup of a checkbox in FacetWP shows the values from db.

How do I set that up in FacetWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your code for this task, **do not forget** to re-index after each name change.

```
/**
 * reindex after adding or updating this filter
 */
add_filter( 'facetwp_index_row', function( $params, $class ) {
    if ( 'new_facet' == $params['facet_name'] ) { // change my_facet to your facet's name/slug
        if ( '1' == $params['facet_value'] ) { // be careful with 1 and 0 as values - https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php
            $params['facet_display_value'] = 'Organic'; // text to display in the facet choices
            }
        if ( '0' == $params['facet_value'] ) {
            $params['facet_display_value'] = 'McDonalds';
            }
    }
    return $params;
}, 10, 2 );
```

[image]